# Implementing a grab object method but Physics.OverlapSphere() returns null if hand contains Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I´m trying to implement a grab function but I have trouble getting my Colliders for grabbing.
Currently I´m using:

```
Collider[] grabbableColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(palm.position, reachDistance, grabbableLayer);
```

to return an Array of Collider within the range reachDistance.
This works fine but if my hand model contains an `Rigidbody` it returns null. I need the Rigidbody in the hand for later usage.

Does anyone know why it returns null if my hand model contains a `Rigidbody`?

Answer (score 0):

Probem is fixed. The issue was that the `Layer` of the Hand was same as of the object I wanted to grab. This caused the method to return null.